# zone-evergreen.js:2952 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/ 404 (Not Found)

Tags: html, django, angular, typescript, django-rest-framework

I am new to Angular and Django. I am trying to create a website that uses Angular as a front-end and Django as a back-end, where Angular sends an Object (which contains name, email & query) to Django using DjangoRestFramework. (posting data from Angular to Django)

**CONTACT FORM SS**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcgD0.jpg)

**HERE IS MY ANGULAR FILES**

**contact.component.html**:

```
       <form #userForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
                <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col-sm">
                              <ul>
                                  <li>Contact No:</li> +91 8425007230 <br><br>
                                  <li>Email:</li>  sanketsbhosale@outlook.com / sanketsbhosale2016@gmail.com
                              </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm s1">
                            <input type="text" required #name="ngModel" [class.is-invalid]="name.invalid && name.touched" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="name" [(ngModel)]=userModel.username>
                            <small class="text text-danger" [class.d-none]="name.valid || name.untouched">Name is Required!</small> <br> <br>
                            <input type="text" required #email="ngModel" [class.is-invalid]="name.invalid && email.touched" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" [(ngModel)]=userModel.email> <br> <br>
                            <small class="text text-danger" [class.d-none]="email.valid || email.untouched">Email is Required!</small>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm s1">
                            <textarea class="form-control" required #query="ngModel" [class.is-invalid]="query.invalid && query.touched" placeholder="Tell me your Query" style="height: 118px;" name="query" [(ngModel)]=userModel.last_name></textarea>
                            <small class="text text-danger" [class.d-none]="query.valid || query.untouched">Please Provide Query!</small>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <button [disabled]="userForm.form.invalid" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left : 330px;">Send Message</button>
        </form>
```

**contact.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PostDataService } from '../post-data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact',
  templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact.component.css'],
  providers:[PostDataService]
})
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {

  userModel;
  constructor(private _dataPost: PostDataService) { }

  onSubmit(){
    this._dataPost.enroll(this.userModel)
    .subscribe(
      response => {
        alert("Data is Submitted")
      },
      error => alert("Error in submitting data"),
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userModel = {
      username : '',
      email: '',
      last_name: '',
    }
  }

}
```

**post-data.service.ts**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PostDataService {

  _url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  enroll(userData): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this._url, userData)
  }
}
```

**HERE IS MY DJANGO FILES**

**settings.py**

```
# here only necessary code I have posted

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10
}

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
]

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    "http://localhost:4200",
]
```

**serializers.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers


class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'email', 'last_name']
```

**URLs.py**(root URL file)

```
From Django.contrib import admin
from Django.URLs import include a path
from rest_framework import routers
From sample.API import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import viewsets

from sample.api.serializers import UserSerializer


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

Comment: try removing the last `/` in `_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/';` make it as `_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users';`

Comment: try running with `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` add your system IP address to the `ALLOWED_HOSTS`, then add the API url with this system IP address to Angular service, before that you can put these Urls in the browser and test the response you get DRF gives you a good UI to check the response

Comment: @SammyJ it's also not working !!

Comment: can you edit the question and add more details of what you have tried now?There would be some changes right, does calling these APIs separately work?

Comment: @SammyJ calling separately through localhost:8000 works charm & also Angular Page works perfectly! But only I am getting a problem in connecting Angular and Django. I am creating a website in which there is one page that contains CONTACT FORM (where the user puts their NAME, EMAIL, and QUERY, which will be sent to Django in JSON format, then it will handle using DRF). I referred this video ==> https://youtu.be/FFvphHyD9Mg.

Comment: Ok,have you tried to give like your ip_address:8000? Does it work then?

Comment: @sammyJ its doesnt work ?? Actually the problem is in Angular-Django connection when i runs website and sends POST request then it says 404 page not found means angular is not connected to Django properly!! OR else can u tell me how can Django accept JSON data from angular without Django-Rest-Framework

Comment: SOLVED !! The problem was in _url ... I used `_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/apiusers/'` and it worked!

Comment: great man,but I am not so sure whether this is correct way, in the `urls.py` try to give like this `path('api/', include(router.urls)),` I just put an extra / here  and then try `_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/'` in angular

Comment: I think it will create more confusion for me .. but I will try... thanks bro for your efforts!